# Gmap Primefaces Geocode customized error message

Tags: javascript, google-maps, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm follow the Primefaces showcase for Geocode function with p:gmap, if I put a real address, it's ok, but if I put an invalid address nothing happens, I only received the message in chrome console "Geocode not found", but I have to catch the event so I can show a custom message to the user.

Looking deeper I found the gmap.js inside the Primefaces library, and there is launching an Primefaces.error("Geocode not found"), but I still have the problem how can I catch that ?

Im using Primefaces 5.2

```
<p:gmap 
  widgetVar="w_gmap_edit" 
  id="gmapId_edit" 
  center="#{tiendasController.centerGeoMap}" 
  zoom="15" 
  type="ROADMAP" 
  style="width:400px;height:450px"
  model="#{tiendasController.mapModel}" 
  onPointClick="handlePointClick_edit(event)"
>
  <p:ajax 
    event="geocode" 
    listener="#{tiendasController.onGeoCodeAction}" 
    onstart="onCompleteGeoCodeEdit(xhr, status, args)"
    update="@this center-form:tiendas-editar-latitud-value center-form:tiendas-editar-longitud-value"
  />
</p:gmap>
```

And the Javascript Function:

```
function geocode_edit() {
  PF('w_gmap_edit').geocode(document.getElementById('center-form:tiendas-editar-direccion-value').value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this:

**View Elements**:

`<a:row>
      <a:label value="" span="2"/>
      <p:commandButton value="#{bundleCommun.btn_recherche}" icon="ui-icon-search" onclick="geocode();" type="button" />
     </a:row>
<p:gmap id="geoGmap" widgetVar="geoMap" center="#{addHubController.centerGeoMap}" zoom="12" type="ROADMAP" model="#{addHubController.geoModel}"
        onPointClick="handlePointClick(event);" style="width:100%;height:400px">
    <p:ajax event="geocode" listener="#{addHubController.onGeocode}" update="@this" />
</p:gmap>`

**Script**

```
<script>
    function geocode() {

        var map=PF('geoMap').getMap();//PERFECT

        var address=document.getElementById('form:address').value;//PERFECT

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();//PERFECT

        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {

            if (status === 'OK') {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('CUSTOMIZED ERROR MESSAGE');
            }
        });
</script>
```

[PRIMEFACES GMAP](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/gmap/basic.xhtml)  / [GOOGLE MAP API, GEOCODE TUTORIAL](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple)

This is working very fine for me. Good Luck

Comment: Thanks Mehdi for your response, I try it but always execute else block, no matter if the address it`s ok or not, it's like if the function return always false.

Comment: @JorgeDominguez I found the solution, I edited my answer & I catched the error with the code above. Good Luck once again

Comment: Hi @MehdiBouzidi , thanks a lot, it works, the only thing is that the goecode event in p:ajax do not execute, so I have to do some adjustments in javascript, but now I can show a message, thanks again.

Comment: @JorgeDominguez Welcome my friend, it cost me a day of researchs but at the end i found the solution & I won a lot of experience. Good Luck